# ImportRow is not working

Tags: .net, asp.net, ado.net

In the following example, its returning me 2 rows, and the importrow does not throw any exception, but when I see the datatable after the foreach its empty and it should have also 2 rows.

```
foreach (int refmDossierId in distinctREFMDossierIds)
{
    DataRow[] datarows =
                    _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Select("REFMDossierID =" + refmDossierId);
    if(datarows.Length>0)
    {
        foreach(DataRow dr in datarows)
        {
            _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Clear();
            _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.ImportRow(dr);
        }
    }

    //2.     foreach master row
    foreach (UC090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterfaceRow row in _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Rows)
    {
```

Comment: I thought the problem was that I was clearing inside the foreach, I moved that line before the foreach, however its not working yet, it gets into the foreach twice, but at the end the datatable is empty.

Comment: One problem that I see is that you're clearing the table before every import, so I'd expect at most one row.  However, maybe a little explanation around what `_uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface` and `UC090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterfaceRow` are, and why you use `DataRow` in the first step and the custom type in the second might give us more to go on.

Comment: Indeed, I would expect one row, but I fixed that and I still see no rows.  these are typed datasets, I just need to filter the datatable and then iterate over the results.

Comment: Have you tried using `foreach (DataRow row in _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface`) rather than `UC090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterfaceRow`?

Comment: its not what I need, I would lose the intellisense of the typed columns

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx) says "If the DataRow that is passed as a parameter is in a detached state, it is ignored, and no exception is thrown."  Could that be the case here?  What happens if you don't clear the table, and just import the rows?  (I know you'll get duplicate rows, but I'm wondering if clearing the same table you did the select on is the issue here.)

Answer (score 5):

Just a hunch, but maybe the fact that you're clearing the table you got the collection of rows from is causing the DataRow collection to be in a detached state?  If that's the case, try `Clone` to make a new `DataTable` that has the same schema, but no rows, and then do the `Import`:

```
foreach (int refmDossierId in distinctREFMDossierIds)
{
    DataTable tempTable = _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Clone();

    DataRows[] datarows = _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Select("REFMDossierID = " + refmDossierId);

    if (datarows.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach(DataRow dr in datarows)
        {
            tempTable.ImportRow(dr);
        }
    }

    foreach (UC090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterfaceRow row in tempTable.Rows)
    {
        //  Do your processing here
    }
}
```

You're current code will wipe the table after the first ID, by the way - which could be problematic if you have more than one ID you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Tim is correct. Example.

```
    Private Sub SortAddress(ds As DataSet)

        Dim sourceTable As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)


        Dim targetTable As DataTable = ds.Tables(0).Clone()

        Dim sorted = sourceTable.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().OrderBy(Function(row) _
                                                                    _matchFirstNumberRegEx.Match(row("Col1")).Value) _
                                                        .ThenBy(Function(row) _
                                                                     _matchFirstNumberRegEx.Replace(row("Col1"), "")).ToList()

        ds.Tables.Remove(ds.Tables(0))

        For Each row In sorted

            targetTable.ImportRow(row)
        Next

        ds.Tables.Add(targetTable)

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer in a simpler form (c# coding) can be viewed as:

```
string dt1Query = "SELECT ColumnName FROM tableName";
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(dt1Query, objConn))
{
    dt1.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
}

DataTable dt2 = dt1.Clone();

foreach (DataRow dt1Row in dt1.Rows)
{
    // some code here if need to work anything out before writing to dt2
    dt2.ImportRow(dt1Row);
}
```

just to help others..