# DataTable.ImportRow not working

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

In my `WinForms` application I'm populating two `DataGridView`'s like below;

```
private void PopulateData()
{
    //Load data
    DataTable dtAll = LoadData();
    DataTable dtSelected = dtAll.Clone();

    dtAll.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtAll.Columns["PK"] };
    dtSelected.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtSelected.Columns["PK"] };

    DataView leftGridView = new DataView(dtAll);
    DataView rightGridView = new DataView(dtSelected);

    dgvLeft.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgvLeft.DataSource = leftGridView;

    dgvRight.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgvRight.DataSource = rightGridView;
}
```

Then in some other place I'm exchanging columns between two `DataGridView` like below;

```
private void ExchangeData()
{
    //Get current row of left grid
    DataRow selectedRow = ((DataRowView)dgvLeft.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).Row;

    //Find the row from all data table
    DataRow foundRow = dtAll.Rows.Find(selectedRow["PK"].ToString());

    if (foundRow == null)
        return;

    //Exchange row between grids
    dtAll.Rows.Remove(foundRow);
    dtSelected.ImportRow(foundRow); 
}
```

But only `dtAll.Rows.Remove(foundRow);` is completing correctly and reflected in the `DataGridView` but the line `dtSelected.ImportRow(foundRow);` doesn't add the row to `dtSelected`. I changed this line to `dtSelected.ImportRow(selectedRow);` but the result is same. Any thoughts?

In [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow(v=vs.110).aspx) something catches my attention was;

> If the new row violates a Constraint it won’t be added to the data
>   table.

Note: This question is not related to following SO posts;
[DataTable.ImportRow is not adding rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824967/datatable-importrow-is-not-adding-rows)
[Why DataTable.Rows.ImportRow doesn't work when passing new created DataRow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035479/why-datatable-rows-importrow-doesnt-work-when-passing-new-created-datarow)
[DataTable importRow() into empty table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856532/datatable-importrow-into-empty-table)
[ImportRow is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037098/importrow-is-not-working)

EDIT: I added the `PrimaryKey` part, `DataView` and `DataRowCollection.Find` method later to incorporate some filtering feature. Without these the code worked as intended.

Another EDIT: I removed the `PrimaryKey` part from `PopulateData` method and modified the `ExchangeData` method as follows;

```
//Get current row of left grid
DataRow selectedRow = ((DataRowView)dgvLeft.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).Row;

//Find the row from all data table
int foundRow = dtAll.Rows.IndexOf(selectedRow);

//Exchange row between grids
dtAll.Rows.RemoveAt(foundRow);
dtSelected.ImportRow(selectedRow);
```

But the issue is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK then it was because of my order of the code to execute. Let me explain.

This was the code I execute for the exchange;

```
//Exchange row between grids
dtAll.Rows.RemoveAt(foundRow);
dtSelected.ImportRow(selectedRow);
```

Here the row is first **deleted** before it's been imported to the `dtSelected` table. That's why `dtSelected` never got the row imported whatever the way I tried.

So changing the order of the code fixes my issue;

```
//Exchange row between grids
dtSelected.ImportRow(selectedRow);
dtAll.Rows.RemoveAt(foundRow);
```

The fear emotion in Inside Out says a phrase which suites this situation. "My Bad"